# presentViewController doesn't work on iOS7, app hangs

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, grand-central-dispatch, presentviewcontroller

I'm using GCD to make sure this happens on the main thread, but even that doesn't fix the issue.

```
- (void)showCat:(NSNotification *)notification {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *navVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Cat"];

            [self presentViewController:navVC animated:YES completion:^{
                //this never happens on iOS7
            }];
    });
}
```

navVC is not nil.

Works fine on iOS8. On iOS7 the app just hangs. Memory usage continuously goes up until it crashes due to memory pressure.

What else could be the cause of this? presentViewController works fine in other areas of the app. This code is called when a notification is received.

Comment: Where did you put this code?

Comment: In a view controller...

Comment: Use the debugger! `presentViewController` causes all kinds of other stuff to try to happen, like `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear:`, and so on. Find out where the hang really is. It sounds like you've got recursive code. Pause in the debugger to find it.

Comment: Also make sure that this scene is compatible with iOS 7. If you use size classes in the storyboard, that is why you are hosed here. There are no size class in iOS 7.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Much nicer than down votes. I'm not using size classes. viewDidLoad gets called in the nav controller, but viewDidAppear does not. Which makes sense because the view never appears.

Answer (score 0):

Actually turned out there was some recursive code in viewDidLayoutSubviews of the presented view controller. Thanks to @matt for the tip. Not sure why this isn't also an issue in iOS8, but nevertheless the problem is fixed.

Goes to show that actually offering advice even if you don't have the entire code base of the project in front of you can still be helpful, rather than simply downvoting from your high horse.